# Manage Alerts Settings in SharePoint 2010

Tags: alert, custom-list

We are currently trying to use a Custom List in our Team Site in SP2010 to manage our customers requests.

The idea is creating a set of rules to alert the relevant contact as follows;

**1**. When the request is submitted by the customer (external SharePoint user with access to the site fills in a request form) a **first alert** should be received by the *Business Owner/Approver*.

**2**. The Business Owner/Approver revises the request and validates the information and from a drop down list sets Approved or Not Approved status. If the selected option is Approved then a **second alert** should be triggered and sent to the *Administrator*.

I feel comfortable creating the first alert so a particular contact gets an email every time a new item is added to the Custom List. However, I don't know how to create the second alert to the Administrator when the Business Owner has selected Approved in the corresponding Drop Down section.

Could you please help?
Thanks :)

Comment: Will you be able to hookup a SharePoint Designer workflow? It may give you greater control over alerts.

Comment: @Ashish Patel - We used to have SP Designer in Windows XP but now we have Windows 7 and it hasn't been re-installed. We could requested, though. We have used workflows before, what do you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the SharePoint object model you can create custom alerts, that are based/triggered upon on a CAML query. It sounds like this could solve your problem. Here is a link to a brief description for SharePoint 2007: http://rickenberg.dk/blog/?p=44

Comment: Hi @Bernd Rickenberg, thank you very much for your post. This seems quite helpful. Unfortunately, we do not command xml very well and our control of the site is quite limited. We only have access to few lists in this Team Site, so I wonder if there is a way to set the second alert up for "dummies" that we could create ourselves. I thought of creating a view of Approved items and set up that alert when changes are made on that view; i.e., inclusion of new approved items would change the view and trigger an alert. Not sure whether this even makes sense...

Comment: Ok, sorry - thought it was a coding question. It seems possible to hook an alert up to a view: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/5943236e-7878-4253-aeae-40c32a306821/

Comment: thanks a lot! this sounds a lot easier for us to set up and maintain.